# Regex match should be 1 or 2 digit but not zero with single digit in date format

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var dateObj = {
  '01/01/2017' : true,
  '1/1/2016' : true,
  '1/1/16' : true,
  '1/1/116' : false,
  '01/11/2016' : true,
  '01.01.2016' : true,
  '01.01_2016' : false,
  '01-0-2016' : false,
  '01-01-2016' : true
};
var failedAttempts = [];
var date_val = "01/01/2017";
var re = /^(\d{1,2})[/.\-](\d{1,2})[/.\-](\d{4}|\d{2})$/;
for(let i in dateObj){
  let result = re.test(i);
  if(result != dateObj[i]){
    failedAttempts.push(i);
  }
}
if(failedAttempts.length > 0){
  console.error('Unit test fails');
  console.log(failedAttempts);
}else{
  console.log('Unit test pass');
}
```

`'01-0-2016' : false` consider this case returns true even it is in wrong format. I want to rewrite the Regex with the digit matches either `1` or `2` but not `0` in `single` digit.

Comment: Are you trying to match number `1` or `2` before first `"/"` character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrict the digit matching patterns with negative `(?!0+\b)` lookaheads:

```
 /^(?!0+\b)(\d{1,2})[\/.-](?!0+\b)(\d{1,2})[\/.-](\d{4}|\d{2})$/
   ^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/51k3To/1)

If you needn't restrict both day month parts, just remove the unnecessary  lookahead.

The `(?!0+\b)` pattern matches one or more zeros followed with a word boundary (that is, there cannot be any letter/digit/`_` after it), and if the pattern is found, the match is failed.

Comment: Note that if `00` is OK and should pass (I do not think it is expected though), just remove the `+` from the lookahead(s).

Answer (score 0):

There could be several ways, I propose:

```
var re = /^(\d{1,2})[/.\-]([1-9]|[0-9]{2})[/.\-](\d{4}|\d{2})$/;
```

Let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex way of validating your input date strings using `dd/mm/yyyy` or `/dd/mm/yy` formats:

```
for(let str in dateObj) {
   var parts = str.split(/[-.\/]/);
   var p = parts[0]*parts[1]*parts[2];
   if (isNaN(p) || p<10 || (p>99 && p<1000)) {
      console.log("Invalid date: ", str);
   }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Invalid date:  1/1/116
Invalid date:  01.01_2016
Invalid date:  01-0-2016
```

1. First we are splitting date string into 3 parts using delimiters `-` or `.` or `/`
2. Then we are multiplying all 3 parts and taking the product for validation
3. Finally we are using `isNaN(p) || p<10 || (p>99 && p<1000` conditions for validation. `isNan` will address all invalid date inputs, `p<=0` will address day, mont or year being zero and last condition will address year part in 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```js
const validateDate = (date) => /^(?:[1-2]\d|0?[1-9]|30|31)([.\/-])(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\1(?:\d{4}|\d{2})$/.test(date)

const testData = [`01/01/2017`, `1/1/2016`, `1/1/16`, `01/11/2016`, `01.01.2016`, `01-01-2016`, `01.0.2016`, `01.01_2016`, `01-0-2016`, `1/1/116`, `41.23.23`]

for (const date of testData){
  console.log(`${date} ${validateDate(date)}`)
}
```